# Replacing the existing axes in ggplot in order to have the same scales on two different plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to do the density plots (please find [data](http://www.filedropper.com/treatment)  ). I have two panels side by side to plot the densities before and after some treatment. Since the limits on X-axis changes after treatment, I wanted to plot both densities on the same scale. The problem arises when I have redefine the axis limit. Here is my code:

```
pretty_breaks_x <- function (n = 10, min_x = 0, max_x = 200, is_limit = TRUE ) {
    if (is_limit == TRUE ){
        pretty_x = scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                                      breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10),
                                      limits = c (min_x, max_x))
    }else {
        pretty_x = scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                                      breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10))
    }
return(pretty_x)
}


prep_density_plot <- function (data_frame,
                               x_in_string_format,
                               group_or_color_variable_in_string_format,
                               x_axis_title_in_string_format,
                               y_axis_title_in_string_format,
                               alpha) {

    g = ggplot (data_frame)
    density = geom_density (aes_string (x = x_in_string_format, y = "..scaled..",
                                        group = group_or_color_variable_in_string_format,
                                        fill = group_or_color_variable_in_string_format,
                                        color = group_or_color_variable_in_string_format) ,
                            alpha = alpha)
    x_axis_title = scale_x_continuous (parse (text = x_axis_title_in_string_format)  )
    y_axis_title = scale_y_continuous (parse (text = y_axis_title_in_string_format)  )

    p = g + density + themes + x_axis_title + y_axis_title

    return (p)

}

load ("~/treatment.RData")
plt_before_treatment = prep_density_plot(df_before_treatment,
                        "value",
                        "treatment",
                        "before",
                        "Density",
                        0.6)

plt_after_treatment = prep_density_plot(df_after_treatment,
                                     "value",
                                     "treatment",
                                     "after",
                                     "Density",
                                     0.6)
plt_before_treatment = plt_before_treatment + pretty_breaks_x(n=5,
                                                      min_x = 2,
                                                      max_x = 7,
                                                      is_limit = TRUE)

plt_after_treatment = plt_after_treatment + pretty_breaks_x(n=5,
                                                  min_x = 2,
                                                  max_x = 7,
                                                  is_limit = TRUE)
```

Reassigning the x-axis throws the following error:

**Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing
scale.**

The x-axis in the resultant image is shifted down. I am wondering how to fix this one.

[image: Density plot of treatment. The new x-axis is shifted down]

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. What do you mean when you say the x-axis is "shifted down"?

Comment: Sorry for that. I wanted no gap between the x-axis and the plot. I know in general this can done by using expand = c(0,0) in scale_x_continuous, but it seems not to be working in my case.

Comment: So you want the x-axis to cross at y=0, rather than just below zero? If so,  you could do `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 1.05), expand=c(0,0))`.

Comment: Instead of making two separate plots, you could stack your before and after data and create a single plot with two facets.

Comment: All good now. Thanks, @eipi10. Nice suggestion about having two facets.